# How do I run virtual machines on a powerful laptop

Tags: virtual-machine

I recently got a new laptop. It has a 750 GB hard drive, 12 GB of RAM, and a 3 GB video card. I have Windows 7 64 installed right now but I have a license for Windows Server 2008R2. I want to use virtual machines for my development environment, running Office, and just about everything else. What is the best way to host virtual machines? Should I buy VMWare or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could certainly buy VMware. VMware does have a couple free versions ([Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) and [Server](http://www.vmware.com/products/server/overview.html)) as well. Or you can use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), which is pretty good too, and is totally free for personal use -- this would be my pick.

Comment: Second the Virtualbox suggestion

Comment: Thanks for the Virtualbox suggestion. I started using it recently and it is awesome.

Comment: Virtualbox randomly reboots and there doesn't seem to be a solution

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for: Installing a Fresh Windows OS to a New Bootable VHD with no Host OS for Boot to VHD http://johnpapa.net/bootoffmetal